# How to convert a video from After Effects to a Android 1.6 compatible format?

Tags: android, video, after-effects

We are creating a video for a splash screen with After Effects. We have try a lot of video configurations and we get it playing in iPhone and Android 2.3, but in Android 2.2 or lower we only see the first frame of the video.

What video configuration have we to use so it can be played in iPhone and Android 1.6 or upper? Can we use another application to transform de video?

The video is 960x640 in landscape orientation.

Regards.

Comment: While I don't have a solution, I feel I should mention this. Android 1.6 only accounts for 0.8% of android versions see http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html. You should consider is it worth the effort for 0.8% of Android users.

Comment: You are right, but the problem also includes 2.2 and 2.1 versions. I will be satisfied if I find a solution for Android 2.1 and upper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tests. This is the video configuration that is OK for all devices I mention:

Codec: MPEG-4

Size: 480x320

FPS: 30

Bitrate: 1200 Kbps

File extension: .mp4

960x640 videos cause problems in iPhone3GS and Android 2.2 and lower so finally we decided to reduce the size of the video.